# Write permission to the web application directory of the virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a compute engine instance on GCP with Centos 7/PHP. When I upload a image file onto my web server through the web pages, It says that the file or directory can not be created.
But, I have set the directory access right to '777' before.
What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `gcloud compute scp` (after installing and setting up the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-yum), if you don't have it) to upload the given file directly to your server's document root within your VM instance, eg.:

```
$ gcloud compute scp image_file.png instance-name:/var/www/html/
```

Otherwise, feel free to provide additional details such as the Web application or interface that you were using and any error messages that you might have been getting: try looking in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` for nginx or `/var/log/httpd/error_log` for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you really have a folder into which strangers can upload arbitrary contents as 777, you need to fix that literally right now. There's nothing stopping someone from uploading a "picture" that's actually a PHP script (or even a shell script, or a compiled binary, or literally anything else, since *everything can be executed*) once your upload feature is up and running.

Without seeing your configuration, my guess is the upload directory that's currently configured doesn't exist yet. Unlimited power in a domain is really only useful if that domain actually exists, I suppose. Some distros don't create an upload directory out of the box, so this isn't that weird, and the PHP's file upload mechanism will do just that -upload a file, that is- without worrying about whether the destination folder must be created first. (It would in fact be Not Good if random strangers could simply pick where and when their ambiguously beneficent files could make their way on to your network.) If that isn't the problem, we're going to need your server configuration file and the PHP script in question.

I would seriously get on top of the directory permissions, by the way. It's a canonical question on this site, and if you're going to be standing in the same room as a computer for the next few decades, it's well worth your time check it out